# How to use auditpol to check the setting, if the category is in Japanese?

Tags: windows, powershell, japanese

I try use powershell to check server audit setting in windows by using command
`auditpol.exe /get /category:"DS Access"`

For some servers, the language is Japanese, the command returned can not find the category:"DS Access",

```
エラー 0x00000057 が発生しました:
パラメーターが間違っています。
```

when I try to use `auditpol.exe /get /category:*` to display all settings find the category name is Japanese.

I try to use `chcp 437` or `chcp 65001` and then run the
`auditpol.exe /get /category:"DS Access"`

```
Error 0x00000057 occurred:
The parameter is incorrect.
```

run  `auditpol.exe /get /category:*` the Japanese character can not display in the powershell window, it shows ??? or blank for the JP characters.

Is there any way to let the command return English character as result like below?

```
Active code page: 65001
PS C:\Windows\system32> auditpol.exe /get /category:"DS Access";
System audit policy
Category/Subcategory                      Setting
DS Access
  Directory Service Changes               No Auditing
  Directory Service Replication           No Auditing
  Detailed Directory Service Replication  No Auditing
  Directory Service Access                Success
PS C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: Try using the policy guids instead. You can find them with `auditpol /list /subcategory:* /r` Check out the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59230314/7411885

Answer (score 1):

Used the guid's in individual queries. GUIDs can be got by:
auditpol /get /subcategory: * /v

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).